# r linear model using dopar

Tags: r, foreach

I am trying to execute a simple GEE model in R. My outcome is a continuous variable, one X(time) which is a 3 level nominal variable(t1,t2,t3), 35,000 repeat observations for 2000 subjects.

```
       `geeglm(y ~ time, data=df, id=ID, family="gaussian", corstr ="exch")`
```

This is taking a long time, 2 hours and still not completed. Recently I came across `foreach` library. I am curious to know if I can run gee using `foreach` library and if this will speedup the process. Any advice on this matter is much apricated. Thanks.

Comment: No, you can't use external parallelization to speed up a model fit.

Comment: Do you even need 35k repeats? If the results using 1k and 2k repeats do not change much, you're done already. Why are you not using a simple ANOVA here? You do not need a glm for gaussian familiies.

Comment: @danlooo, great suggestion about ANOVA, I will try that approach.